# Parsing return value from one method as two arguments for another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a function `def findSpace(aBookcase):` which returns `return row,column` and another function which takes `def setName(self, row, column, name):`.

Now, when I execute `aBookcase.setName(findSpace(aBookcase), name)` I get `TypeError: setName() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)`.

How can I make it parse the result from findSpace() as two arguments to function setName(), without changing findSpace(), because **I have other code already depend on it**

Comment: Does `setName` in a Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findSpace` returns a tuple. That is one object. `aBookcase.setName` expects three separate arguments, in addition to the instance itself. Unpack the result and then use the arguments:

```
r,c = findSpace(aBookcase)
aBookcase.setName(r, c, name)
```

In Python 3.5 or higher, you can simply use `*`:

```
aBookcase.setName(*findSpace(aBookcase), name)
```